# Add method in que to later execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this `PerformTransaction();` method in my mvc banking application. and my requirment is `insertTransaction();` and  `updatetransaction();` this are important methods to execute.

After execution of this 2 to methods I want to show success message to user and in backgound remaining methods should be in process to be execute later. because everytimes this methods are getting called and its badly impact on my application performance. I am using isolation level read committed.

This logging process is time consuming and that should run in background. (I am using Linq to sql)

**What will be the proper way to achieve this. which methodology should i use?**

```
public ActionResult PerformTransaction(int id = 0)
{
   insertTransaction();
   updatetransaction();
   //later execution
   insertlogg();
   updatelogg();
   logger();

    return Json(new
            {
                success = status.Status,
                message = status.Message
            });
}
```

Comment: Scott Hanselman wrote a good post on [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.Net](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest to you is to use `System.Threading` so it will continue after execution.

**For Example:**

```
public ActionResult PerformTransaction(int id = 0)
{
   insertTransaction();
   updatetransaction();
   //later execution
   System.Threading.Thread TInsert = new System.Threading.Thread(insertlogg());
   TInsert.Start();
   System.Threading.Thread TUpdate = new System.Threading.Thread(updatelogg());
   TUpdate.Start();
   System.Threading.Thread TLogger = new System.Threading.Thread(logger());
   TLogger.Start();

   return View("Edit");
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information about threading.

I don't see any example of your success log so I don't put it in here.

Comment: what if after success user immediately request another page. then this thread will be still there in process or it will cancelled?

Comment: @user3111053 It will be automatically closed when the process is complete or have error, But not will close while still not finished.